# Overwriting config file for my CMS

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I'm looking for the best options besides storing the values in a mySQL db, I'd rather have a singular file for my defines or variables.

What I need to do is have a `configuration.php` file which I have one already for my admin panel which I've filled out, but inside the admin panel they will be able to edit stuff such as the page title or anything basic for that matter. So I was thinking I could have a `static_configuration.php` file which would hold all the data that I need.

**EX Before Edit (static_configuration)**

```
define("_TITLE","{TITLE}");
define("_DESC_","{DESC}");
define("_KEYW_","{KEYW}");
```

My idea is to use this as a template, and when they edit, I'll `fopen` `fwrite` etc to basically overwrite `configuration.php`

**EX After Edit (configuration.php)**

```
define("_TITLE_","Great Turns");
define("_DESC_","Great turns is a turned based RPG online game......");
define("_KEYW_","great turns online rpg, great turns");
```

My idea works, and I've implemented it something like this so far

```
if(file_exists('static_configuration.php')){
      $file= file('static_configuration.php', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
      foreach($file as $configs){
        $channel.= str_replace(array('{TITLE}','{DESC}','{KEYW}'),array("BASE TURN","This is a website","cool,dude,whats up"),$configs);
      }
    $data = fopen("configurations.php","c+");
     fwrite($data,$channel);
     fclose($data);
  }
```

Question in hand is this a safe bet or should I take a different route? I mean I need to make the code a little bit more dynamic using `$_POST` requests but so far it does work. Please enlighten me as I am just trying to learn and write a simple CMS (My thoughts are don't use something unless you know how it works), college also will have me writing a lot of these methods so I am asking out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you escape the data correctly before defining them, i think you will not have probs.

PS : for reading and writing files, check [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) :P

But if its more for curiosity, check [gettext()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) methods ;) (i think you do this for language)

Comment: thanks surely I will look at these methods. I was hoping I was causing a huge strain on the server or anything like that.

Comment: mmhhh, well, dont do it on each visit, better cache those files once they are done, and call them later when you need them, or yes, you should overload server very fast ^^

Comment: No they are only called when the user will submit a form. Then it those defines will be used later in other files. Only changed when the user wants them to

Comment: ah well, then just check the user isn't spaming the form, and you should not get overloaded =)

Comment: Thanks Bob, yeah I am going to add a detection of how long ago the form was submitted and if any changes were made.